# SELECT top value of each country

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Using Google BigQuery, this is the expected output

Find the top vendor (display vendor name) by GMV in each country

| Country_name | Vendor_name | total_gmv |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Taiwan | Sweet Chinese Desserts | 4029.62 |
| Thailand | 9th Cafe House | 576.0 |
| Singapore | IC House | 123.772 |

My current method (I cannot figure out how to proceed)

```
SELECT O.country_name, V.vendor_name, O.gmv_local as total_gmv, PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY O.country_name ORDER BY O.gmv_local) AS Pct_rank
FROM Orders O
JOIN Vendors V
  ON O.vendor_id = V.id
ORDER BY 4 DESC;
```

- Order Table: vendor_id, country_name, gmv_local
- Vendor Table: id, vendor_name

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Alright, I will change this habit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` method in your query.

**Query :**

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Ord.country_name, vn.vendor_name, ROUND(SUM(Ord.gmv_local), 2) AS total_gmv,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ord.country_name
                              ORDER BY SUM(Ord.gmv_local) DESC) rn
    FROM `data2.orders` AS Ord
    LEFT JOIN `data2.vendor` AS vn
        ON Ord.vendor_id = vn.id
    GROUP BY Ord.country_name, vn.vendor_name
)

SELECT country_name, vendor_name, total_gmv
FROM cte
WHERE rn < 2
ORDER BY country_name, total_gmv DESC;
```

**output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After trying out different methods, I have figured out the answer.

```
SELECT DISTINCT country_name, FIRST_VALUE(vendor_name) OVER (PARTITION BY country_name ORDER BY country_name) as vendor_name, total_gmv 
FROM(
SELECT country_name,vendor_name,total_gmv,rank_id
FROM(
SELECT O.country_name,V.vendor_name, O.gmv_local as total_gmv, RANK() over 
(PARTITION BY o.country_name ORDER BY O.gmv_local desc) as rank_id
FROM Orders O
JOIN Vendors V
  ON O.vendor_id = V.id) a
WHERE rank_id = 1) b
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You can use subquery to fetch vendor_name of each country based on max(total_gmv) instead of window function. something like :
select * from order_table a where total_gmv = (select max(total_gmv) from order_table where a.country_name = country_name) this will give you top vendor id for each country